# Searching for a Sitecore item by ID using SitecoreRocks

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-rocks

The Sitecore graphical interface has the native ability to traverse the Sitecore content tree and search for an item given an item ID.

Is there any way to accomplish the same thing using the Sitecore Rocks plugin for Visual Studio?  I've tried plugging in the ID into the "Find" box at the top of the Sitecore Explorer to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please check below picture, I highlighted the field where you enter the id and the press Go. You need to have database selected where are you searching.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, so I guess I was using the right approach after all.  How do I actually select the database - do I just click "master" or whichever?

Comment: yep, just click master